# Excel for Mac conditional formatting not working (at all)

Tags: microsoft-excel

My Conditional Formatting button stopped working (MacBook Air, MacOS Mojave 10.14.2, Excel 2016). This is true for existing files with the formatting done previously, and new files. None of them are in shared mode, and all are on my local drive (both hard drive and thumb drive). I made sure no groups of cells were selected on other worksheets. In fact, a new trial file with a very simple data set has only one tab. Whenever I click the Conditional Formatting button, the only thing that happens is the three color window control buttons (red, orange, and green at top left of screen) go gray.
 Any help with this appreciated. I use this function frequently.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It will help us not go over already covered ground

Comment: Other than rebooting the computer, I don't know what to try. It's hard to understand why clicking a function button would disable the application/window functions (the red, orange, green buttons). The "share" option is disabled. The only other unusual issue is the "open recently used file" option does not work on some files, and sometimes doesn't work at all.

Comment: What version number of Excel 2016 for MAC?

Comment: Version 15.25 (160817)